# Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript: key cannot be nil

Tags: swift, firebase, xcode9

Hello I'm getting this error simply trying a short database write with firebase on iOS using swift. My code is crashing immediately after hitting the Firebase().Database().reference() line. I am running Firebase 4. I have imported Firebase into my AppDelegate and am calling this code inside of func application.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
let myDatabase = Firebase.Database().reference()
myDatabase.setValue("We've got data!")
```

Comment: May be you want to use this: `Database.database().reference()` instead of `Firebase.Database().reference()`

Comment: I think you might not have set the Firebase configuration. Think there is a plist you need to download from your firebase database page. It would have been better if firebase had handled the error more elegantly, could be a feedback for Firebase.

Comment: @3stud1ant3 you got it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase database treats data as key/value pairs, so when you want to setValue make sure it is currently under a key value. By calling Firebase.Database().reference() you are just accessing the root path of your database, which no key value is pointed. You need to explicitly address the key (e.g. Firebase.Database().reference().child("data").setValue("We've got data!"))
or using childByAutoId().setValue() to let firebase help you generate a key ID.